# How to connect Google Cloud SQL via Google App engine Flex to botnet core app?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform

I have a .NET Core 2.2 app using a PostgreSQL DB. 
Now I want to deploy it on Google Cloud App Engine Flex and Google Cloud SQL PostgreSQL.

I tried [the official way](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/postgres/connect-app-engine?hl=en_US) and [found this](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/dotnet-docs-samples/tree/master/appengine/flexible/CloudSql), where I found that you have to use `$ gcloud beta app deploy` instead of `$ gcloud app deploy`

My app.yaml configuration file:

```
env: flex
runtime: aspnetcore
beta_settings:
  cloud_sql_instances: "<SQL-NAME>=tcp:<PORT>"
```

The issue is that I get this error:

> Trying to connect to
>   Host=127.0.0.1;Port=XXX;Username=XXX;Password=XXX;Database=XXX;
>   Application startup exception: System.Net.Sockets.SocketException
>   (111): Connection refused

Do I have to include special libraries into .NET Core 2.2 to support Google App Engine?

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to include any special libraries in .NET Core 2.2 rather than those that are already included in the [Quckstart](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/dotnet-docs-samples/tree/master/appengine/flexible/CloudSql) that you have shared above, unless of course you are using any additional libraries in your code.

I have tried the quickstart and deployed my .NET GAE app that connects to CloudSQL PostgreSQL database.

Taking a look at your `app.yaml` configuration file I can see that there is an issue with it. Also based on the error message you are getting I assume that you are having an issue in your `appsettings.json` file as well.

Based on the quickstart of GitHub that you shared, the configuration when deploying should be:

**app.yaml**

```
runtime: aspnetcore
env: flex

beta_settings:
    cloud_sql_instances: "[PROJECT_ID]:[INSTANCE_REGION]:[INSTANCE_NAME]=tcp:[TCP_PORT_NUMPER]"
```

- TCP Port number for PostgreSQL: **5432**
- TCP Port number for MySQL: **3306**
- To find the **Instance connection name** which is the part before **tcp**, you can go to `Cloud Console > SQL > [YOU_INSTANCE_NAME]` and you can find the entire string under `Instance connection name`

**appsettings.json**

```
{
  "CloudSQL" : {
    "Database" : "PostgreSQL",  // Set to "PostgreSQL" when using a PostgreSQL database.
      // [START gae_flex_mysql_settings]
    "ConnectionString": "Uid=[USER_ID];Pwd=[PASSWORD];Host=cloudsql;Database=[DATABASE_NAME]"
      // [END gae_flex_mysql_settings]
  }
}
```

- **Database** should be `PostgreSQL` as also specified by the comment
- **ConnectionString** should be filled with your own data that you used to setup the database
- The **Host** part should be `cloudsql` when you are deploying and `127.0.0.1` when running locally.

`127.0.0.1` indicates that the database is running locally and the `cloudsql` string indicates that it should use the connection string name. Based on the error, I assume that you used the `127.0.0.1` to test locally but then forgot to change it back when you were deploying.

Comment: In App.yaml I used the string you described
I don't need the Database field in app settings because I only used the Postgres Client libraries directly. 
I tried the cloudsql Hostname, but I'm not sure if this is correct, because the sql Proxy is just started on the host itself so localhost should be fine. This is also supposed in the office docs:

Comment: But thanks for you detailed answer. I will just use a ec instance with the db proxy directly. It seems that I'm not ready for hip cloud shit. ;)

Comment: "AppSettings": {
    "ConnectionString": "Host=127.0.0.1;Port=5433;Username=<USER>;Password=<PASS>;Database=<DBNAME>;",

Comment: I would recommend giving it another try by following the tutorial [dotnet-docs-samples](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/dotnet-docs-samples/tree/master/appengine/flexible/CloudSql) from the beginning. I haven't experienced any `Connection refused` issues, when following it. Also you have mentioned `Port=5433`, however the default one is `5432` as specified in [PostgreSQL documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/app-postgres.html) and in the tutorial it self as well. In case this is not a typo, please double check the port and try again.